Issue with App-Ads.txt and Ads Not Showing on My Mobile Application
Summary: I tried correcting the app-ads.txt placement by creating a new GitHub Pages repository and hosting the file at the root URL (https://mjiyan.github.io/app-ads.txt) as required by AdMob. I expected the ads to resume displaying in my mobile application after the AdMob dashboard recognized the app-ads.txt file and updated its status to "Ready." However, even after these changes, the ads are still not showing in the app.
Here’s the timeline of what happened and the steps I’ve taken so far:
1. Initial Setup:
Initially, I misunderstood how to correctly place the app-ads.txt file. I hosted my website on GitHub Pages (https://mjiyan.github.io/magmat) and added the app-ads.txt file under that URL (https://mjiyan.github.io/magmat/app-ads.txt).
However, AdMob requires the app-ads.txt file to be placed at the root folder of the domain (e.g., https://mjiyan.github.io/app-ads.txt).
2. AdMob Dashboard Feedback:
Initially, the AdMob dashboard displayed:
"100% of queries: no app-ads.txt file found."
Despite this, ads were showing when I first published the app. Later, I noticed that the ads disappeared on my phone, which prompted me to investigate further.
3. Correction Attempt:
To resolve this, I created a new GitHub Pages repository specifically for hosting the app-ads.txt file. I created an empty website in the repository and placed the app-ads.txt values inside the index.html file. This setup made the root URL for app-ads.txt:
https://mjiyan.github.io/app-ads.txt.
4. AdMob Dashboard Update:
After this change, the AdMob dashboard updated the message to:
"App-ads.txt was found for 78% of the queries, and merchant accounts were authorized."
Additionally, the "Review Required" status changed to "Ready."
5. Current Problem:
Despite the updates on the AdMob dashboard, ads are still not showing on the mobile application.
My Questions:

Did I miss any critical steps in configuring the app-ads.txt file?
Is there a delay between fixing the app-ads.txt issue and ads starting to show again?
Are there any other factors I should check to ensure the ads display properly?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance for your help.
